# Bash - Evaluate CPU and Memory performance of a single command that run instantly

Tags: linux, bash, performance, memory, cpu

I'm writing a Bash script to evaluate time/CPU/memory performances of commands given as input to the script.

I implemented the evaluation of time by using `date` command, but I have issues to evaluate CPU and memory performance related to the single command. I know that I can use `top` command but it shows me only runtime processes.

My issue is that if I run the script by giving as input the command, I don't know previously the assigned PID to this command, and if I want to evaluate an instant command as `whoami`, I cannot find it when I use `top` command, even if I use pipe on them.

I think for commands that needs more time, I would like to calculate an average, but for commands like `whoami`, `ls` or similar instant commands, I don't have idea how I can get the CPU and memory performance for that specific instant of time.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: For the time, did you try `time myCommand`?

Comment: And for the time and cpu, install `time` (the command `time` https://www.gnu.org/software/time/ ) and use `/bin/time command`

Comment: What do you means by "memory performance"? The peak memory usage or the memory throughput?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet @KamilCuk Thank you for the comments. I don't use `time` because by `date` I can reach nanoseconds precision. For someone could be meaningless, but my target is to compare the performance of different commands, so also nanoseconds order is worth for me.

Comment: @JérômeRichard I mean peak and average memory usage, but also memory throughput could be a nice addition. Thank you

Comment: @Develobeer If you think that `date` will provide a better accuracy than `time` you should probably reconsider this choice: `date` will give you a nanosecond accurate measure of an extremely noisy signal.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet for `date` command, the noise comes from which elements? Or better, how this noise can affect it?